# Adding $y=x$ line on a pcolor plot: it doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
u=list(map(lambda x:pow(10,x),np.arange(-2,1+0.1,0.1).tolist()))
v=list(map(lambda x:pow(10,x),np.arange(-2,1+0.1,0.1).tolist()))

[X,Y]=np.meshgrid(u,v)
Z1=np.ones((len(u),len(v)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pcm = ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z1,norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=Z1.min(), vmax=Z2.max()),
                   cmap='PuBu_r',edgecolors='black')
plt.xscale('log', basex=10)
plt.yscale('log', basey=10)
fig.colorbar(pcm, extend='max')
plt.plot([u[0], v[0]], [u[-1], v[-1]], 'k-', lw=2)
plt.title('test1')
plt.show()
```

I want to show a diagonal line (equation y=x) on the graph. The line plt.plot([u[0], v[0]], [u[-1], v[-1]], 'k-', lw=2) that I added doesn't do the job.

Could you help me to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the elements:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pcm = ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z1,norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=Z1.min(), vmax=Z2.max()),
                   cmap='PuBu_r',edgecolors='black')
plt.xscale('log', basex=10)
plt.yscale('log', basey=10)
fig.colorbar(pcm, extend='max')
plt.plot([u[0], u[-1]], [v[0], v[-1]], 'k-', lw=2) # Here the difference
plt.title('test1')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The points should be in the form [xvalues], [yvalues]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
u=list(map(lambda x:pow(10,x),np.arange(-2,1+0.1,0.1).tolist()))
v=list(map(lambda x:pow(10,x),np.arange(-2,1+0.1,0.1).tolist()))

[X,Y]=np.meshgrid(u,v)
Z1=np.ones((len(u),len(v)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pcm = ax.pcolor(X, Y, Z1,norm=colors.LogNorm(vmin=Z1.min(), vmax=Z1.max()),
                   cmap='PuBu_r',edgecolors='black')
plt.xscale('log', basex=10)
plt.yscale('log', basey=10)
fig.colorbar(pcm, extend='max')
# the points should be in the form [xvalues], [yvalues]
plt.plot([u[0], u[-1]], [v[0], v[-1]], 'k-', lw=2)
plt.title('test1')
plt.show()
```

[image]